# Why does this work on my local server but not my remote server. (checking for existing user accounts during registration)

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my code.

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "register")) {


$existsQuery = "SELECT email FROM userinfo"; 
$existsResult = mysql_query($existsQuery);
$exists="false";
while($derp=mysql_fetch_array($existsResult)){
    if($derp['email'] == $_POST['email']){
    $exists="true";
    break;  
    }

}


if($exists=="true"){

$message = "Username (".$_POST['email'].") already exists, please try again. ".$derp['email']."";  

}

else { 

date_default_timezone_set('EST');
$hour = date("h") + 1;
$date = date("l jS \of F Y $hour:i:s A");

$insertSQL3 = sprintf("INSERT INTO loginfo (userEmail, login_stamp) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($date, "text"));

$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO userinfo (email, password) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['password'], "text"));

$insertSQL2 = sprintf("INSERT INTO loggedin (email) VALUES (%s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$Result2 = mysql_query($insertSQL2, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$Result3 = mysql_query($insertSQL3, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "dashboard.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));

 }

 }
```

And I get these Errors When I try to login as a new user.

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home4/dunag/public_html/register.php on line 49

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home4/dunag/public_html/register.php:49) in /home4/dunag/public_html/register.php on line 91

Comment: As per the literally thousands of duplicates on this site, your queries have failed, you utterly failed to account for that failure, and compounded that failure into epic failures. A simple `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())` will tell you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Remember that `mysql_query` is a deprecated interface that’s being removed from PHP. You should plan to migrate to a modern replacement like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) in order to keep your application compatible with future versions.

Comment: I initially had a a conditional where it just checked the count. But I was getting this error. So I panicked and looped it up.

now that I know I just had to select the db first Ill go back to that.

Comment: @MattThompson There's a lot of Dreamweaver code out there that's painfully obsolete. Just because you use Dreamweaver doesn't mean you're stuck in the past. You can use a modern framework inside of it if you set up your environment correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the contents of mysql_error after you attempt connecting. That should be able to tell you a little more. Here is the function definition.

```
string mysql_error ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

My assumption is that the remote server cannot connect to the database.

Comment: Derp. The error said there was no database. I put a mysql_select_db() statement at the beginning and it worked.

Comment: Gotta love down votes on a push in the right direction. So many people here suck. Whoever thought programmers could be a part of a community site where they don't treat each other like losers should be smacked for it.

Comment: Haha, happens all the time. Keep in mind if you don't want to loop through every email, you could put a conditional in your query; e.g. `WHERE email LIKE '$email'`. This will leave you open to security vulnerabilities, which is probably accounting for a lot of the snark other users are giving you.

Comment: Yah, and Im gonna change it back to my old code instead of looping through every email.